# Creating a Table from a List with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

My list looks like this: [["t0","b0",x0],["t1","b1",x1],......,["tn","bn",xn]
with x : 0<=x>=100.

Now I need to create a table with a JavaScript file which displays the t's are in column 1, b's column 2 and x column 3.

I've searched for an answer for days, tried to modify simpler codes but one way or another it did not work.

In a next step I want to control the "filling" of a progressbar with my x.

*In HTML:*

```
<div id="bar1" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%" aria-valuenow="x" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">x%</div>
```

So I need to get this code in every x-column and be able to access both x variables.
I got the one inside my container with:

```
document.getElementById("bar1").innerHTML
```

no clue how to change the x in the div-properties.

So here is what one row in the table looks like:

```
  <tr>
                    <th id="t_titel18" scope="row">T18</th>
                    <td id="t_des18">T18_Beschreibung
                    </td>
                    <td><div class="progress">
                <div id="t_bar18" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="x" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">x%</div>
              </div></td>
                    
                  </tr>
```

So I need access to every separate  column to change my properties there.

But just by answering the first part of my Question you are helping me, a lot.
Thanks

Comment: Please remove the first sentence from your question and rephrase it so that it's clear you are looking for a specific library.

Comment: Please add your code snippet to others to refer and give the solution based on it

Answer (score 0):

You just create two nested loops. The outer loop processes each row, while the inner loop processes the columns in each row:

```
var myList = [["t0","b0",0],["t1","b1",1],["t2","b2",2],["t3","b3",3]];
var html = "";
$.each(myList, function(rowNumber,rowData){
    html += "<tr>";
    $.each(rowData, function(columnNumber,columnData){
        html += "<td>"+columnData+"</td>";
    });
    html += "</tr>";
});
$("#myTable").html(html);
```

I created a jSFiddle for you where you can see this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/4qat9aff/3/
I am using jQuery, but you can of course use built-in Javascript functions like *for...of*.

I don't see why you need a progress bar, this will load so quickly that the user won't even notice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, with this im creating a default HTML table , in my case I am using a template (for wich I need the progress bar).So i need to change properties of a div container.

Comment: let me clear this: I need to access every column in the loop separatly because the template related code, I need to add to the properties, differs there.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to do.
Where is the template coming into the picture?